# Handling ties when ranking from the highest to the lowest

Tags: php

I am trying to make a ranking manager for a small project.The totals are stored in the database.I can easily get the max and min using mysql and also arrange the records descending.The problem comes in when there is a tie.I need to show a tie in the form:1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7, etc.The repeated numbers will show the ties.I have been thinking of ways of achieving the above but i need more ideas;mine is seems long and complicated.

Can anybody share his/her idea of doing the ties.

Comment: You want to highlight the same score? And please show your own idea.

Comment: Let me post it once i am done,since i still need to return an array and populate them with data from mysql.

Comment: Hi Tom,check out the final code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941898/building-ranking-system-with-data-from-the-database/2944786#2944786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
  'A'=>19,'B'=>18,'C'=>17,'D'=>17,'E'=>16,'F'=>15
);

$rank = 0;
$lastScore = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach( $data as $name=>$score ) {
  if ( $lastScore !== $score ) {
    $lastScore = $score;
    $rank += 1;
  }
  printf("%s %d (%d)\n", $name, $score, $rank);
}
```

prints

```
A 19 (1)
B 18 (2)
C 17 (3)
D 17 (3)
E 16 (4)
F 15 (5)
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just do that in SQL as well? The records with duplicate ranks will still get output, however the order within the tie will be undefined.

```
SELECT id, rank FROM mytable ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

Ah, looks like I misunderstood the question, thanks Matchu. This could still be achieved with a relatively simple SQL query. The key is using a subquery to count the distinct scores that have already passed.

```
SELECT id, score, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT score) + 1 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE score < outerscore.score 
  ORDER BY score ASC
) AS rank
FROM mytable as outertable
ORDER BY score ASC;
```

Comment: I think the point is that the rank is not defined in the database; he needs to calculate it from the scores.