# Production Postgres query returning different values than local sqlite query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have a query based on the answer to this question: [Handling ties when ranking from the highest to the lowest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939061/handling-ties-when-ranking-from-the-highest-to-the-lowest/2939079#2939079)

Given this dataset:

`Name | Score`
`Mike | 5`
`John | 3`
`Mary | 3`
`Matt | 0`

The following query returns a user array containing the correct values.

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT id, score, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT outertable.score) + 1
FROM users WHERE score > outertable.score ORDER BY score ASC) AS rank 
FROM users as outertable GROUP BY outertable.id, outertable.score
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 30")
```

`Name | Score | Rank`
`Mike | 5 | 1`
`John | 3 | 2`
`Mary | 3 | 2`
`Matt | 0 | 3`

Running the exact same query in Postgres on Heroku, I receive this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Adding a `LIMIT 1` on the inner select results in the following funky data:

`Name | Score | Rank`
`Mike | 5 | nil`
`John | 3 | 2`
`Mary | 3 | 2`
`Matt | 0 | 2`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem in your SQL.Change it to this:

```
SELECT  name,score, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT score) + 1
     FROM users WHERE score > outertable.score 
     ) AS rank 
FROM users as outertable 
GROUP BY outertable.name, outertable.score
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 30
```

I have tried it without no problem!You could also try this statement.They have the same result.

```
select a.name,
       a.score,
       count(distinct b.score)+1 as rank
from 
    users a left join users b
    on a.score > b.score
group by
    a.name,a.score
order by a.score desc limit 30
```